# TypeError: $(...).parent(...).delegate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using `WebGrid` in my project. When I inspect my code(of `aspx` page) in browser, I found error on console. It is : `TypeError: $(...).parent(...).delegate is not a function` and when I click on error line it shows me following CODE:

```
$(function() {
$('table[data-swhgajax="true"],span[data-swhgajax="true"]').each(function() {
var self = $(this);
var containerId = '#' + self.data('swhgcontainer');
var callback = getFunction(self.data('swhgcallback'));
/*here comes the error*/
$(containerId).parent().delegate(containerId + ' a[data-swhglnk="true"]', 'click', function() {
$(containerId).swhgLoad($(this).attr('href'), containerId, callback);
return false;
});
})
});
```

Main ASPX page code:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <div id="MainDashboardDiv">
        <div class="UpperLiveTiles">
            <div id="RecentDiv">
                <a href="../CRM/RecentCRMRequest">
                            <h4 class="RequestTitle">Recent Requests</h4>
                        </a>
                        <%Html.RenderAction("RecentRequests", Model); %>
                    </div><!--End of RecentDiv -->
            <div id="PriorityDiv">
                        <a href="../CRM/HighPriorityCRMRequest">
                        <h4 class="RequestTitle">High Priority Requests</h4>
                        </a>
                        <%Html.RenderAction("PriorityRequests", Model); %>
                    </div><!--End of PriorityDiv -->
            </div><!--End of UpperLiveTiles -->
    </div><!--End of MainDashboardDiv -->
<%} %>
```

Partial View1 Code:

```
<%    
    var grid1var = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "Id", fieldNamePrefix: "grid1", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "FirstDiv", canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);%>
<div id="FirstDiv">
    <%=
        grid1var.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid1" }, tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader",
        columns: grid1var.Columns(
                grid1var.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "ID", canSort: true),
                grid1var.Column(columnName: "Requester_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
                grid1var.Column(columnName: "Estimated_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
                grid1var.Column(columnName: "Date_Created", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Date_Created.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
         ))
    %>
</div>
```

Partial View2 Code:

```
<%    
    var grid2var = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "Id", fieldNamePrefix: "grid2", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "SecondDiv", canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);%>
<div id="SecondDiv">
    <%=
        grid2var.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid2" }, tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader",
        columns: grid2var.Columns(
                grid2var.Column(columnName: "Id", header: "ID", canSort: true),
                grid2var.Column(columnName: "Requester_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
                grid2var.Column(columnName: "Estimated_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
                grid2var.Column(columnName: "Date_Created", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Date_Created.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
         ))
    %>
</div>
```

I don't know what type of error this is.

---

**I finally catch the error:**

It is just because of ready-made jquery menu I use in system is using old jquery. And it is conflicting with New Jquery version. I have removed that menu and everything is working fine.

Comment: May I know, Which jquery version you are using?

Comment: @AnoopSharma, It's 1.8.17.

Comment: Can you debug the value of `$(containerId).parent()` ?

Answer (score 2):

use `$(document)` instead:

```
$(document).delegate(containerId + ' a[data-swhglnk="true"]', 'click', function() {
    $(containerId).swhgLoad($(this).attr('href'), containerId, callback);
    return false;
});
```

`or you can place the id or class of the parent.`

### note:

`.delegate()` needs jQuery version 1.4.2 atleast

`.live()` needs jQuery version 1.3 atleast (*`deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9`*)

`.on()` needs jQuery version 1.7+

So if you are using `jquery 1.9` then use `.on()`.

Comment: This code is generating at run time. I am not writing it. I don't have any idea how to change it.

Comment: Okay but that would be nice if you post that code part too.

Comment: I have added it. You can view it now.

Answer (score 0):

If Your requirement is to bind event for that element on the fly Please refer $(document).delegate("your precise selector","event","function to call").

As I see you have said that this code is being generated on run time. Can you please give us code snippet of you aspx as well as generated code?

Comment: Sure, I have added it in my post.